# Numbers in url change layout

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a website. I have two identical webpages, one named 10x10x10 and the other named tenx. Same stylesheet. But the aren't exactly the same. The layout shifts a little to the right or left on the 10x10x10 page. All the other pages are the same. Isn't it allowed to use numbers in a url? Or something else?

Comment: Can you post URL of your pages? But I dont think name url should not affect to your CSS.

Comment: Are you sure you are using the same css? Maybe there is a scrollbar on one of those pages which causes the shift to the left.

Comment: Lol! somehow I zoomed in in one page, and my browser remembered that XD so 10x10x10 stayed zoomed